# Android Proguard keep a folder

Tags: android, release, proguard

Is there a way to insert all files in a directory in /libs folder in Proguard?
I got a library which has lots of files, it would be absurd to add them all.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The standard Android build processes (And, Eclipse, Gradle) automatically include all library jars for you. You shouldn't specify them again, or you'll get lots of warnings about duplicate classes.

If you have a custom build process, you can just specify the directory:

```
-injars libs
```

ProGuard recursively reads directories, zips, ears, wars, and jars.